# rendering and styling of html for tagging system To-Do List

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have followed Hartl's tutorial to make a ToDoList with a tagging system, also with the help of this [word guide](https://medium.com/@sherzelsmith/add-a-filtering-multiple-tag-system-with-autocomplete-to-your-rails-model-in-rails-5-1bf88cd53e9) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBa2qs9CFZQ).

However, there seems to be a problem with my html file when I tried clicking a tag to filter out all microposts containing the same tags. I need regular intervalled ones like this(I had to show a sample home page before the tagging system got implemented as this feature is really new and I tried to improvise from the tutorial).

[image: regular]

instead of this, which is my current view.

[image: Wrong]

Does anyone have any clue how to solve the problem and tell me what I am actually doing wrong judging from the error message log. I'm really bad with working with these html files embedded with Rails due to the fact the rendering occurs almost everywhere. Moreover, I didn't really understand how the tutorial was able to the filtering possible the moment we click the tags. I do not need the text box as per the home page feed. MoreoDo inform me if more information is needed.

Html code for involved files in log

micropost/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Filtered Micropost Page</h1>
<div class = "col-md-8 offset-2">
  <% @microposts.each do |micropost| %>
    <p><%= truncate(micropost.content, length: 50) %></p>
    <p><small>Tags: <%= raw micropost.tags.map(&:name).map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %></small</p>
        <span class="timestamp">
            Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
            <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
              <%= link_to "Done", micropost_path(micropost), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Keep up the good work!" } %>
            <% end %>
        </span>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Footer.html.erb

```
<footer class="footer">
  <small>
    A To-Do Manager</a>
    by <a href="https://www.google.com"> Prashin</a> for
    <a href = "http://www.google.com">Prashin</a>,
    based on the rails tutorial guide by
    <a href = "https://www.railstutorial.org/book">Michael Hartl</a>.
  </small>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><%= link_to "About",   about_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <br>

  <br><br>
  <p align = center>
  <%= link_to image_tag("AikenDueet.jpg", alt: "KenyuDueet"),
            'www.google.com' %>
            <br>I can do it!</p>
</footer>
```

header.html.erb

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to "To-Do App", root_path, id: "logo" %>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Users <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to "All Users", users_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Administrators", users_admin_path %></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <% if logged_in? %>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Account <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "#{current_user.name}", current_user %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Account Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li>
                <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: :delete %>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Log

```
  Rendered microposts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (199.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (55.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 278ms (Views: 259.1ms | ActiveRecord: 11.4ms)
```

Comment: can you make it so that only the relevant portions of the code is included in the question? see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `small` tag is not closed properly (`</small</p>` in `micropost/index.html.erb`) producing many nested `small` tags resulting in gradual font decreasing.